# SQL expression or columns in the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, group-by

This is more like theoretical question than a problem. Let's say I have a table which has three columns `id, Country1, Country2`.

I want to run simple example query:

```
SELECT 
     CASE WHEN Country1 = '' THEN Country2 ELSE Country1 END AS [Country], 
     COUNT(id) AS [Countries_count]
FROM ExampleTable
GROUP BY 
     CASE WHEN Country1 = '' THEN Country2 ELSE Country1 END
```

The query will work regardless I will put whole non aggregate expression

```
GROUP BY 
     CASE WHEN Country1 = '' THEN Country2 ELSE Country1 END
```

or only columns which are in this expression

```
GROUP BY 
     Country1,
     Country2
```

in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Should I put into `GROUP BY` clause every single non aggregated expression (which sometimes are really huge) or can I put only columns from those expressions? And if I can/cannot, why?

Comment: Which dbms? (Doesn't look completely ANSI/ISO compliant.) Data type for column employment_date? (Since you check employment_date = ' '...)

Comment: In **SQL Server**, every non-aggregated columns **must be** in the `GROUP BY` list of columns. Other RDBMS might allow different approaches.

Comment: Well, good point - example with the dates wasn't best choice. I changed it to avoid data types offtopic ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking which of these is more appropriate for the query:

```
GROUP BY CASE WHEN Country1 = '' THEN Country2 ELSE Country1 END
```

or

```
GROUP BY Country1, Country2
```

The answer is usually the first one.  But, it depends on what you want to do.

Consider the following data:

```
ID       Country1       Country2
 1                             A
 2              A              A
 3              A
```

This query:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN Country1 = '' THEN Country2 ELSE Country1 END) AS [Country], 
       COUNT(id) AS [Countries_count]
FROM ExampleTable
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN Country1 = '' THEN Country2 ELSE Country1 END)
```

Returns one row with the overall count

```
A    3
```

This version

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN Country1 = '' THEN Country2 ELSE Country1 END) AS [Country], 
       COUNT(id) AS [Countries_count]
FROM ExampleTable
GROUP BY Country1, Country2
```

Returns three rows:

```
A    1
A    1
A    1
```

Under most circumstances, I would want one row with the count of 3.  There may be some circumstances where this is the desired output.